# NFS Server for WS2022 is not working afer migrating to a different drive letter

Tags: nfs, windows-server-2022

One should mean that this is a prette strait forward task.

I am using Windows Server 2022 and installed the "Server Role" "NFS Server".
I shared the D:\ drive as "dev_files" by using the Explorer Properties dialog window on that drive.
After that I was able to use this share on several UNIX based machines.
Same directory is also shared via CIFS with the same name.

Later I decided to change the drive letter, so I removed the share config and changed the drive letter to K:\ . Afterwards I configured the drive exactly the same as before. No error during configuration. Now the share can't be accessed from an Ubuntu and ans Solaris machine although everything should be configured fine.

When I remove the share and rename it with e.g. "dev_files2" then the new share works. It seems, that the old name "dev_files" is somehow broken and is remembered somewhere in the OS.

I tried to do multiple reboots.

I tried to restart the NFS service.

I also removed the hidden "._nfs" directory.

It seems that the old share name can't be used any more with the new K:\ drive.

Tried to find alternative methods to list and clear available NFS shares but had no luck. I found `Get-NfsShare` but this PS command seems to be not available on my system.

Hope one can help!